# PHP Echo Help on Moving

Tags: php, html

Hello i have written a PHP and HTML file, i want to move the echo from displaying on top of my web browser into one of the divs in the html file, any ideas on how to do that? the code is below, ive looked everywhere but have found nothing.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pwrd = $_POST['pwrd'];
    include ('../includes/db_connect.php');
    if(empty($user) || empty($pwrd)){
        echo 'Please enter a Username and Password!';
    }else{
        $user = strip_tags($user);
        $user = $db->real_escape_string($user); 
        $pwrd = strip_tags($pwrd);
        $pwrd = $db->real_escape_string($pwrd);
        $pwrd = md5($pwrd);
        $query = $db->query("SELECT user_id, username FROM user WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pwrd'");
        if($query->num_rows ===1){
            while($row = $query->fetch_object()){
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row->user_id;
            }
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        }else{
            echo 'Wrong Username and Password!';
        }


    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
<script scr="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php include '../includes/header.php' ?>
<div id="container">
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <p>
        <label>Username</label><input type="text" name="username" />
        </p>
        <p>
        <label>Password</label><input type="password" name="pwrd" />
        </p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
</div>
<?php include '../includes/footer.php' ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you must defining into a variable

your rule

```
echo 'Please enter a Username and Password!';
```

must be

```
$response = 'Please enter a Username and Password!';
```

and you can put it into a html tag like this

```
<div><?php echo $response; ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pwrd = $_POST['pwrd'];
    include ('../includes/db_connect.php');
    if (empty($user) || empty($pwrd)){
        $msg = 'Please enter a Username and Password!';
    } else{
        $user = strip_tags($user);
        $user = $db->real_escape_string($user); 
        $pwrd = strip_tags($pwrd);
        $pwrd = $db->real_escape_string($pwrd);
        $pwrd = md5($pwrd);
        $query = $db->query("SELECT user_id, username FROM user WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pwrd'");
        if($query->num_rows ===1){
            while($row = $query->fetch_object()){
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row->user_id;
            }
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        } else{
            $msg = 'Wrong Username and Password!';
        }


    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
</head>
<body>
<?php include '../includes/header.php' ?>
<div id="container">
    <?php
    if ($msg) {
        echo $msg;
    }
    ?>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <p>
        <label>Username</label><input type="text" name="username" />
        </p>
        <p>
        <label>Password</label><input type="password" name="pwrd" />
        </p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
</div>
<?php include '../includes/footer.php' ?>
</body>
</html>
```